# Scrolling two listview inside one LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I am trying to scroll the listview inside one Linear Layout but it is not working as i want. I am attaching one image for the more explanation.
This is my Layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/findSelected"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                            android:background="@drawable/flat_selector_green"
                            android:text="Next"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Image explanation [image]

I know it s not the good approach to use the listview but i have to do this with this way.

Comment: Do you meaning  you want list1 with item 1,2 list2 with item 3,4,5,6,7 =>list 1,2,3,4,5,6,7?

Comment: @tinysunlight yes i want that all the values first scroll and then the second list element is scroll

Comment: Why do you need the `ScrollView`? `ListView`s scroll on their own.

Comment: You can put all data in one list.Why don't you put them togather?

Comment: @MikeM. when i remove the scrollview i second list is scroll but not the first

Comment: If you still have the ListViews' `layout_height` attributes set to `wrap_content`,  that's probably causing that. Set the ListViews' `layout_height`s to `0dp`, and their `layout_weight`s to `1`. Then change the `layout_height` of the LinearLayout that your Button is in to `wrap_content`, and remove its `layout_weight`.

Comment: thanks @MikeM. but i am not trying to divide the scroll view in two part. I am trying do that first all the element of my first list is scroll and then the second list

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that easily with ListViews and ScrollViews. You'd have to intercept and manipulate touch events on the ListViews. That doesn't really sound like a fluid interface anyway. Kinda counterintuitive.

Comment: @MikeM. it means that the only solution is to use the single one?

Comment: Or split the screen between the two. Or use the v4 support library, and use RecyclerViews in a NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ScrollView from your xml code, Because ListView have their own Scroll doesn't require ScrollView.Then code will work as you want. Second List will be shown after showing every item of first ListView.

Comment: thanks @Gaurav but when i do this my second list is scroll but not the first

Answer (score 0):

> According to android docmentation

You should never use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=mooc&utm_term=android&utm_content=l1_scrollview&utm_campaign=training) with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.

**First** you user card view as top parent it seem you will use it as child of list view as I guess , if my guessing is correct this not wise to use two list view as child.

**Second** In any case you want use two listview in same view , its recommended to separate between them with view (TextView , ... etc).

the solution

1- remove scroll as it useless.

2- add weight to your list view as wrap content in your case mean whole view.

3- recommend add view to separate between list.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="false"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wholeview"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

        />
            <!-- recommended to add view here -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/findSelected"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks @MinaFawzy but when i try this solution my listview is divided in two eqaul part and i want that the list will scroll once

Comment: the first list scroll at the first part and the second is scroll in the second part but actually i want that my first list scroll complete then my second automatic scroll

Comment: why you dont put all element in one listview then

Comment: actually i am working on a old project where the two tabs are maintain and two list are maintain but now the demand of project change to remove the the tabs and show the single list now the problem is that both list has different adapter and model and the item which is selected has go to the different url.